# How to find connected components in a matrix using Julia

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, graph, julia

Assume I have the following matrix (defined here in Julia language):

```
    mat = [1 1 0 0 0 ; 1 1 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 1 1]
```

Considering as a "component" a group of neighbour elements that have value '1', how to identify that this matrix has 2 components and which vertices compose each one?

For the matrix ***mat*** above I would like to find the following result:

Component 1 is composed by the following elements of the matrix (row,column):

```
    (1,1)
    (1,2)
    (2,1)
    (2,2)
```

Component 2 is composed by the following elements:

```
    (3,5)
    (4,4)
    (4,5)
```

I can use Graph algorithms like [this](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/algorithms.html#connected-components) to identify components in square matrices. However such algorithms can not be used for non-square matrices like the one I present here.

Any idea will be much appreciated.

I am open if your suggestion involves the use of a Python library + PyCall.  Although I would prefer to use a pure Julia solution.

Regards

Comment: Search for: "flood fill"

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion helped me to realize that my problem was related to images problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Image.jl`'s `label_components` is indeed the easiest way to solve the core problem. However, your loop over `1:maximum(labels)` may not be efficient: it's `O(N*n)`, where `N` is the number of elements in `labels` and `n` the maximum, because you visit each element of `labels` `n` times.

You'd be much better off just visiting each element of `labels` just twice: once to determine the maximum, and once to assign each non-zero element to its proper group:

```
using Images

function collect_groups(labels)
    groups = [Int[] for i = 1:maximum(labels)]
    for (i,l) in enumerate(labels)
        if l != 0
            push!(groups[l], i)
        end
    end
    groups
end

mat = [1 1 0 0 0 ; 1 1 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 1 1]

labels = label_components(mat)
groups = collect_groups(labels)
```

Output on your test matrix:

```
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,2,5,6] 
 [16,19,20]
```

Calling library functions like `find` can occasionally be useful, but it's also a habit from slower languages that's worth leaving behind. In julia, you can write your own loops and they will be fast; better yet, often the resulting algorithm is much easier to understand. `collect(zip(ind2sub(size(mat),find( x -> x == value, mat))...))` does not exactly roll off the tongue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple (though i can't provide python code):

1. collect all 1s into a list
2. select an arbitrary element of the list generated in step1 and use an arbitrary graph-traversal algorithm to traverse all neighbored 1s and remove visited 1s from the list generated in step 1
3. repeat step2 until the list generated in step 1 is empty

In pseudocode (using BFS):

```
//generate a list with the position of all 1s in the matrix
list pos
for int x in [0 , matrix_width[
    for int y in [0 , matrix_height[
        if matrix[x][y] == 1
            add(pos , {x , y})

while NOT isempty(pos)
    //traverse the graph using BFS
    list visited
    list next

    add(next , remove(pos , 0))

    while NOT isempty(next)
        pair p = remove(next , 0)
        add(visited , p)
        remove(pos , p)

        //p is part of the specific graph that is processed in this BFS
        //each repetition of the outer while-loop process a different graph that is part 
        //of the matrix

        addall(next , distinct(visited , neighbour1s(p)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Paul. Your algorithm is clear and I suppose I could have implemented it in Julia or Python. However, I found another suggestion using functions that already exist in Julia language. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just got an answer from julia-users mailing list that solves this problem using Images.jl, a library to work with images in Julia.

They developed a function called "label_components" to identify connected components in matrices.

Then I use a customized function called "findMat" to get the indices of such matrix of components for each component.

The answer, in Julia language:

```
    using Images

    function findMat(mat,value)
        return(collect(zip(ind2sub(size(mat),find( x -> x == value, mat))...)));
    end

    mat = [1 1 0 0 0 ; 1 1 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 1 1]

    labels = label_components(mat);

    for c in 1:maximum(labels)
        comp = findMat(labels,c);
        println("Component $c is composed by the following elements (row,col)");       
        println("$comp\n"); 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use `Graphs.jl`, for a graph `g` there is the convenient  [`connected_components(g)` function.](https://juliagraphs.org/Graphs.jl/dev/algorithms/connectivity/#Graphs.connected_components-Union%7BTuple%7BAbstractGraph%7BT%7D%7D,%20Tuple%7BT%7D%7D%20where%20T)