# Performance slowdown when using Julia's built-in functions

Tags: performance, julia

A research group I am a part of has recently decided to try migrating to Julia from our previous coding language, because of, among other things, its claimed high-speed performance as compared to other user-friendly languages. However, in our initial translations of code snippets, one of my partners noticed that using Julia's built-in functions (specifically rather simple ones such as 'find') causes about a tenfold drop in speed as compared to using simple looping techniques. Has anyone else encountered this, or are there other probable causes we should look into?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without any details, but there are  a few obvious pitfalls that you should know about. Read about them [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/).

Comment: Very likely you are doing everything in global scope.

Comment: As mentioned by other commenters, this question is not specific enough to be a good fit for StackOverflow. This is why it has attracted down-votes and votes-to-close. I understand the constraint about posting proprietary code, but perhaps you can construct a simple working example without giving away anything proprietary? If you could do this, I think this would be a very good question...

Answer (score 6):

Pardon the comment-for-an-answer, since I lack the rep to do a proper comment...

What I understand about Julia is that it is usually better to write loops if you are fishing for maximum performance. This has been true for quite a while; see, e.g., Dahua Lin's [post about devectorizing expressions](http://julialang.org/blog/2013/09/fast-numeric/). (**edit:** but it may change in the future; see Colin T. Bowers' discussion about multithreading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780503/why-devectorization-in-julia-is-encouraged/) and in comment below).

Keep in mind that judging performance can be tricky. I actually use `find` a lot in my own code since I can succinctly ask for the `Int` indices of the nonzeroes in a "sparse" `Vector` that is not obscenely long. `find` is relatively flexible, speedy, and clear compared to an equivalent loop. For example:

```
# problem dimensions
p = 10000
k = 10

# a "sparse" vector with k random nonzeroes
b = zeros(p)
b[1:k] = randn(k)
shuffle!(b)

# use `find` to get the indices
@time bidx = find( x -> x .!= 0.0, b)

# is `find` faster than looping?
function find_nonzeroes(b, k)
    bnz = zeros(Int,k);
    j = 0
    @inbounds for i = 1:length(b)
        if b[i] .!= 0.0
            j += 1
            bnz[j] = i
        end
        j >= k && break
    end
    return bnz
end

@time bnz = find_nonzeroes(b, k);

# are results same?
println("Return arrays equal? ", isequal(bidx,bnz))
```

On my machine, after running everything twice, the results are:

```
0.001795 seconds (10.03 k allocations: 158.402 KB)
0.004593 seconds (2.57 k allocations: 131.876 KB)
Return arrays equal? true
```

But if you jack up the dimension of `b`, say to `p = 1000000`, then the results are quite different:

```
0.028236 seconds (1.00 M allocations: 15.261 MB, 7.70% gc time)
0.005493 seconds (2.57 k allocations: 131.876 KB)
Return arrays equal? true
```

The `find_nonzeores` function is more convoluted and less flexible than `find`, but it scales better to higher `p`. In high dimensions the tradeoff may be worth it, especially if you often call `find` in your code.

Since you offer no details about what you ported to Julia, then it is difficult to offer you any more specific advice than that. The Julia page on [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/) is my go-to reference, and re-re-re-reading it has often helped me improve my code's speed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comment. I am going to edit my code to use find_nonzeroes, and compare that timing to the looping. We are working on a scale of tens to hundreds of thousands of iterations for the scope. I only was not super specific because I'm not entirely certain that I'm allowed to post bits of our code/details about it in public.

Comment: Nice answer. But I thought it worth pointing out that once native multi-threading is available (experimental routines are already in v0.5) the *devectorize everything* heuristic will no longer necessarily be true. This is only in my head as I answered a SO question on exactly this point a couple days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780503/why-devectorization-in-julia-is-encouraged/)

Comment: @ColinTBowers thanks for the heads-up! And having spent a lot of time thinking about how to parallelize my own numerical calculations, I eager look forward to native multithreading in Julia.

Comment: No probs, glad to help :-)  Actually, one thing I should add to the above comment for future readers is that any calculation that can be done by `BLAS` should *not* be devectorized, as `BLAS` optimisations will trump additional temporary memory allocations almost every time.