# Why is this (very simple) vectorized code orders of magnitude slower than Numpy?

Tags: vectorization, julia

I know very well Julia's philosophy concerning vectorization and the like, and I can accept having my code run even ten times slower than Numpy, but why does this code run *much, much* slower than Numpy? Maybe there is a mistake in the code; I can't imagine the issue is related to using vectorization rather than loops.

I am using vectorization because my requirements are not strong; furthermore memory allocation doesn't seem to be that incredible (and it proves to be very fast with Numpy). The code is also easy to read.

The following piece of code is written in Python; it computes a generalized continued fraction over a part of the complex plane. The continued fraction is defined by two different functions; I use this code for plotting pictures on this blog: https://kettenreihen.wordpress.com/

The Python code is below; it computes 640x640 values in about 2 seconds:

```
def K(a, b, C):
    s = C.shape
    P1 = np.ones(s, dtype=np.complex)
    P2 = np.zeros(s, dtype=np.complex)
    Q1 = np.zeros(s, dtype=np.complex)
    Q2 = np.ones(s, dtype=np.complex)
    for n in range(1, 65):
        A, B = a(C, n), b(C, n)
        P = A*P2 + B*P1
        Q = A*Q2 + B*Q1
        P1, P2 = P2, P
        Q1, Q2 = Q2, Q
    return P2/Q2
```

The following Julia code should do the same, but it takes 2 or 3 minutes for computing the same thing.

```
function K(a, b, C)
    s = size(C)
    P1 = ones(Complex, s)
    P2 = zeros(Complex, s)
    Q1 = zeros(Complex, s)
    Q2 = ones(Complex, s)
    for n = 1:64
        println(n)
        A, B = a(C, n), b(C, n)
        P = A.*P2 + B.*P1
        Q = A.*Q2 + B.*Q1
        P1, P2 = P2, P
        Q1, Q2 = Q2, Q
    end
    return P2./Q2
end
```

Comment: Just FYI, Julia philosophy on vectorization might not be what you think it is. For whatever historical reason, many people seem to think Julia discourages vectorization in favour of loops. This is not correct. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780503/why-devectorization-in-julia-is-encouraged/34782346#34782346) for more detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are allocating matrices with an abstract element type: the `Complex` type is an abstract supertype for all specific `Complex{T}` types. What you want here is arrays of some concrete element type like `Complex128 == Complex{Float64}` or `Complex64 == Complex{Float32}`. Presumably in NumPy `dtype=np.complex` refers to a specific complex type, probably the equivalent of `Complex128`.

If you want to write code that is generic and will work for different kinds of `C` matrices, then assuming `C` is a complex matrix and what you want is to create matrices of ones and zeros of the same element type and shape, you can just call the `ones` and `zeros` functions on `C` to get matrices with the right element type and shape:

```
function K(a, b, C)
    P1 = ones(C)
    P2 = zeros(C)
    Q1 = zeros(C)
    Q2 = ones(C)
    for n = 1:64
        println(n)
        A, B = a(C, n), b(C, n)
        P = A.*P2 + B.*P1
        Q = A.*Q2 + B.*Q1
        P1, P2 = P2, P
        Q1, Q2 = Q2, Q
    end
    return P2./Q2
end
```

Hopefully that helps the performance. You might be able to get even more performance by pre-allocating three matrices and doing operations in place, rotating through the matrices. However, the convenient syntax support for that hasn't made it into a stable release yet, so on Julia 0.5 it would still be a little verbose, but could get you a performance boost over the vectorized version.

Comment: This was obviously the explanation; I made the change and the code is now running fast enough. Thank you!